# Php 5.3 or 6 windows install

Tags: php, apache, httpd.conf

How do I install latest versions of PHP as Apache 2 module?
PHPIniDir directive throws error.
And what's more important, there's no php5apache2.dll file or similar in latest distributions of PHP!

[Example distr php 5.3](http://windows.php.net/downloads/snaps/php-5.3-nts-win32-VC9-x86-latest.zip)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [PHP QA site](http://windows.php.net/qa/), if you are using PHP with Apache 1 or Apache2 then you need to be using the VC6 release candidates, not the VC9.  VC9 is for use with IIS.

Since the link you provided in your question goes to a VC9 download, I would assume that's what you downloaded, and I'd say you should go download the VC6 version instead.